# Invalid Hostname - DNS change

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, domain-name

I ping my site on pingdom.com over here (http://tools.pingdom.com/ping/) and got result 
**invalid host name.**
then i check my **DNS HEALTH** and got result as follow

> Delegation

**Everything is fine**

> name server

**The name server failed to answer queries sent over TCP. This is probably due to the name server not correctly set up or due to misconfgured filtering in a firewall. It is a rather common misconception that DNS does not need TCP unless they provide zone transfers - perhaps the name server administrator is not aware that TCP usually is a requirement.**

My website is not getting open in browser..!!
so i think this is DNS problem can you tell me how to fix this..!!
These are the results..!!
[**Pingdom Ping**](http://tools.pingdom.com/ping/?target=ameeto.com&o=2&save=true)
[**Pingdom DNS Check**](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=ameeto.com&timestamp=1313437140)

Comment: Please post your zone name if you want help with DNS resolution issues.

Comment: **h.gtld-servers.net**

Comment: That's not your domain.  What's the full address of your website?

Comment: @Basic Bridge, it seems very unlikely that DNS zone is yours.  I very much doubt you are running one of the global top level domain servers.

Comment: @bvoretq7 hey i was just telling glob domain server name..!!
check the full details of my web from intodns here  http://bit.ly/qDZWPY and from pingdom here http://bit.ly/p45ZO1

Comment: ... so your zone is `ameeto.com` then?

Comment: What do you expect from a not-configured DNS server? Set your DNS records and everything will work smoothly.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `A` record for `ameeto.com`.
There is no record whatsoever for `www.ameeto.com`

These are fundamental errors: The DNS system cannot return information that does not exist.
Correct these problems (Create entries in your DNS zone. Contact your ISP for help) and see if your site starts working...

```
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52114
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ameeto.com.            IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  SOA dns4.fizine.com. abhimanyusharma003.gmail.com. 2011081501 7200 7200 172800 7200
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  NS  dns1.fizine.com.
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  NS  dns2.fizine.com.
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  NS  dns3.fizine.com.
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  NS  dns4.fizine.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  NS  dns4.fizine.com.
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  NS  dns1.fizine.com.
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  NS  dns2.fizine.com.
ameeto.com.     38400   IN  NS  dns3.fizine.com.

;; Query time: 60 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.50.1#53(192.168.50.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 15 16:03:09 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 228
```